# Set position of edit text cursor based on user touch position Android

Tags: android, set, position, touch, text-cursor

I try to make some kind like note application in android xperia or samsung galaxy...
What I wanna do is to set the cursor of edit text position follow the touch position from user.

In normal edit text whenever we touch the edit text area, cursor will always positioned at the end of our characters or between the characters..
So The notes is some kind like being appended with many characters so we can move the cursor wherever we want...
I've tried to appended many blank spaces. but it wont help... Cursor only can move on 1 line only..

Is there any solution for this?
Thanks before.....